# How to get the affected rows of the Zend_DB_table?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

After you do get the number of rows affected when you do `$table->delete($query)` does it return the number affected rows?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
$result = $db->query($sql); 
$affectedRows = $result->rowCount();
```